# Priority of tuple (un)packing with inline if-else

Tags: python, tuples, operator-precedence, iterable-unpacking, order-of-execution

Apologies in advance for the obscure title. I wasn't sure how to phrase what I encountered.

Imagine that you have a title of a book alongside its author, separated by `-`, in a variable `title_author`. You scraped this information from the web so it might very well be that this item is `None`. Obviously you would like to separate the title from the author, so you'd use split. But in case `title_author` is None to begin with, you just want both `title` and `author` to be `None`.

I figured that the following was a good approach:

```py
title_author = "In Search of Lost Time - Marcel Proust"
title, author = title_author.split("-", 1) if title_author else None, None
print(title, author)
# ['In Search of Lost Time ', ' Marcel Proust'] None
```

But to my surprise, `title` now was the result of the split and `author` was `None`. The solution is to explicitly indicate that the else clause is a tuple by means of parentheses.

```py
title, author = title_author.split("-", 1) if title_author else (None, None)
print(title, author) 
# In Search of Lost Time   Marcel Proust
```

So why is this happening? What is the order of execution here that lead to the result in the first case?

Comment: `title_author.split("-", 1) if title_author else None, None` is a tuple, but the first element is the whole ternary expression `title_author.split("-", 1) if title_author else None` and the second element is `None`.

Comment: Tuples are generated from left to right without precedence (lower as ["lowest"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)), so the *priority* is `((title_author.split("-", 1)) if title_author else None), None`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny That was the information that I was looking for. If you have a source for that and can post it as an answer, I'll accept it. The current answers do not specify why this is the order in which the tuple is generated but I am looking for a source/explanation.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are looking for? The question already demonstrates the order of execution, so it's not clear what you expect on this. As for "why" - well, because that's the precedence, so again it's not clear what you expect here. Are you looking for the formal elements in use here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
title, author = title_author.split("-", 1) if title_author else None, None
```

is the same as:

```
title, author = (title_author.split("-", 1) if title_author else None), None
```

Therefore, `author` is always `None`

---

**Explaination**:

From [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-assignment_stmt)

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that
> this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter
> yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of
> the target lists, from left to right.

That is to say, the interrupter will look for `(x,y)=(a,b)` and assign value as `x=a` and `y=b`.

In your case, there are two interpretation, the main differece is that :

1. `title, author = (title_author.split("-", 1) if title_author else None), None`
   is assigning two values (a list or a None and a None) to two variables and no unpacking is needed.
2. `title, author = title_author.split("-", 1) if title_author else (None, None)` is actually assigning one value (a list or a tuple) to two variable, which need an unpacking step to map two variables to the two values in the list/tuple.

As option 1 can be completed without unpacking, i.e. less operation, the interrupter will go with option 1 without explicit instructions.

Comment: I figured that out, but _why_ is that the same? What are the rules in Python precedence that lead to that execution. I am looking for sources.

Comment: @bram-vanroy If title is `None`, then author will be `None` too. You can't have a null book with an author

Comment: That's not what I mean. My question is, how is it defined in Python internals that a tuple is formed from left to right before packing? How does Python now "I expect 2 items in the tuple, and so now I will try to generate a tuple from left to right". Where is this order specified.

Comment: @BramVanroy Python doesn't know and especially doesn't care that you expect 2 items. Go ahead and make the same assignment with a target list of 0, 1 or 3.

Comment: I feel like this answer would be even more useful if it were to point out that the left hand side isn't actually an expression, but a sequence of expressions. The "," is evaluated outside of an expressions precedence rules.

Comment: Strictly speaking, unpacking happens in the first case too. According to the cited documentation, *single* object is assigned to the target list, which in both of our cases results in unpacking, as there's an assignment of iterable object on the rhs to a target list.